# Changing SharePoint tenant name in O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, tenant

We made the mistake of using a very long domain name:

```
https://<25 characters>.sharepoint.com/
```

But have recently purchased a 3 letter domain name so we want it to be:

```
https://<3 characters>.sharepoint.com
```

Is this something we can configure in O365 and/or SharePoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, no this isn't possible. There is a future program from Microsoft which will allow you to change SPO/ODfB tenant domain URLs like you're wanting to, but this isn't available as of yet. See [Enable renaming the site collection URLs](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13217277-enable-renaming-the-site-collection-urls) for more information from Microsoft.